# Download a dynamically generated file using PHP

Tags: php, file, download

This might sound really "nooby" but I need to find a way for PHP to download an XLS file to a server folder. This file is not stored in another server, it is dynamically generated with another PHP script.
This is what I got from browsing the web but it's not working:

```
  <?php
  $url = "http://localhost/ProyectoAdmin/admin/export_to_excel.php?id=1&searchtype_id=2";
  $local_file_path = './xls_tmp/Report.xls'; 
  $xlsFile = file_get_contents($url);
  file_put_contents($file_path,$xlsFile);
  ?>
```

I'd really appreciate any hint.

Comment: Please define your problem. **not working** is not really a problem description.

Comment: With **not working** I meant that when I run the PHP, the file is not found in the xls_tmp folder.

Comment: Any error messages? What is your error reporting level? Is `display_errors` turned on?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an end quote on your second line.

It should be:  `$local_file_path = './xls_tmp/Report.xls';`